# Woman Bringing their little girls to shul

Tags: tefilla, women, synagogue, children-parenting, tefillah-betzibbur

The Birkei Yosef states (regarding bringing children to *shul*) that *“It’s prohibited [for a father] to sit his young child in **front of him** during tefillah [davening].”* (*Mishnah Berurah* 96:4)

Why does the Birkei Yosef says לפניו and not לפניה? 
There are also woman who bring in their daughter(s) - that are below *chinuch* - into the *erzas nashim*, which disturb the *tzibbur* just as much as boys do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as Double AA commented, לפניו is not exclusively male. In Hebrew, when referring to a group of males and females, the male form is used. That also applies when the reader is of unknown gender.

The Chida (author of Birkei Yosef) wrote this several hundred years ago. In that time, it was not common for women or girls to come to shul at all.
Additionally, i've noticed that even today, the women's section in Sefardic shuls is pretty small, and it's not so common for them to come.

Taking all these points together, it would make sense that this would apply to women as well.

Comment: *and it's not so common for them to come.* I've noticed the opposite

Comment: @Scimonster, please give me an example of when לפניו is used for a group of males and females.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Umm, right here? It's just something i've noticed in Hebrew.

Comment: Give me an example.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I don't know about "לפניו" specifically (besides this example), but masculine forms' being used for generic (male or female) people is all of the place. E.g., מי שאחזו קורדיקוס and כל מקדש שביעי... שכרו הרבה and השוכר את הפועלים and אלו מציאות שלו and and and and....